# How to find the answer to a XOR hash if I have the key & one number

Tags: c++11, hash, encryption-symmetric

I have a little routine that makes up a cumulative XOR hash. It's as if it is a savings account which gets bigger, cumulatively daily.. but in this sense we're saying the answer is being generated cumulatively and the key is always present.

I have taken a string of chars

pseudo code:

```
char H[10] = { "ABCDEFGHI", "\0" };
```

and I used 9 32-bit numeric keys to hash them in XOR encryption.

I did it like this:

```
for (i;i<10;i++)
    bitset<32> K ^= H[i] ^ NUMKEY[i];
```

Now this makes it impervious without the calculus plotting I did (see what I did there?) So `K` is an accumulation of calculus points, which are completely predictable according to calculus.

as far as I know, to undo it, I do

```
for (i;i<10;i++) {
    X=0;
    X ^= K ^ NUMKEY[i];
}
```

Is there other math involved? I think I have to take that `X` and do a little `K - X` to find the true derivative.

Here's the current routine I have for it. But I'm not getting what I'm looking for.

```
for_each (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), \
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), \
    [&] (long x) {
    t=s_nop(t,0);
    cred.push_back(t);
    alpha = static_cast<long>(cred[size]);
    delta = static_cast<long>(x);
    lambda ^= (alpha ^ delta);
    size++;
});

for (;i<bn;i++) {
    alpha =  static_cast<unsigned long>(cred[bn-1-i]);
    int m = lambda.to_ulong(), n = alpha.to_ulong();

    long hash1 = abs((m-n-1)%256-1);
    delta = static_cast<unsigned long>(hash1);
    btrace.push_back(hash1);
    cout << hash1 << " ";
}
```

Please have a safe and Merry Christmas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: XOR is commutative, you could precalculate the XOR of your NUMKEYs  and apply it at the end of either operation. XOR all your values together, then XOR by the precalculated value to encrypt. For decryption, instead of repeatedly XORing your key by itself do it once against the precalculated value. you'd have the original result of XORing all your values together. Is that what you want? If you wanted your original values you can't XOR them together (unless you want to recover one by XORing the other nine)

Comment: Could you give me a code sample? It sounds like you know what I need. Thank you for the input. @dtudury

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might really want is a one time pad.  (the snippet is javascript as pseudocode moving in that direction)

```js
//ignore these top 3 functions (they're just for printing output)
function appendLine(text, target, space, color) {
  var line = document.createElement("div");
  line.style.border = "1px solid " + color;
  line.style.padding = line.style.margin = space;
  line.style["font-family"] = "monospace";
  line.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  target.appendChild(line);
  return line;
}
function makeSection(title) {
  var d = appendLine(title, document.body, "5px", "#dddddd");
  var results = document.createElement("div");
  d.appendChild(results);
  return function(result) {
    appendLine(result, results, "2px", "#eeeeee");
  };
}
function toHex(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(n){
    var h = (n >>> 0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while(h.length < 8) h = "0" + h;
    return h;
  }).join(",");
}

//your message
var H = "ABCDEFGHI".split("").map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0)});
//your secret encoding key
var NUMKEY = Array.apply(null, Array(9)).map(function(){return Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 32)});

//what you're doing
(function() {
  var section = makeSection("what you're doing:");
  section("ABCDEFGHI as array of 32bit numbers: " + toHex(H));
  section("NUMKEY: " + toHex(NUMKEY));
  var K = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    K ^= H[i] ^ NUMKEY[i];
  }
  section("K: " + toHex([K]));
  var X = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    X ^= K ^ NUMKEY[i];
  }
  section("X: " + toHex([X]));
})();

//what you're trying to do
(function() {
  var section = makeSection("what you're trying to do:");
  section("ABCDEFGHI as array of 32bit numbers: " + toHex(H));
  section("NUMKEY: " + toHex(NUMKEY));
  var Hs_XORd = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Hs_XORd ^= H[i];
  }
  section("H's XOR'd together: " + toHex([Hs_XORd]));
  var NUMKEYs_XORd = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; i++) {
    NUMKEYs_XORd ^= NUMKEY[i];
  }
  section("NUMKEY's XOR'd together: " + toHex([NUMKEYs_XORd]));
  var K = NUMKEYs_XORd ^ Hs_XORd;
  section("K: " + toHex([K]));
  var X = K ^ NUMKEYs_XORd;
  section("X (should be the same as H's XOR'd together): " + toHex([X]));
})();


//what I think you mean to be doing (one time pad)
(function() {
  var section = makeSection("what I think you mean to be doing (one time pad):");
  section("ABCDEFGHI as array of 32bit numbers: " + toHex(H));
  section("NUMKEY: " + toHex(NUMKEY));
  var K = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; i++) {
    K[i] = H[i] ^ NUMKEY[i];
  }
  section("K (encoded message using NUMKEY as one time pad): " + toHex(K));
  var X = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < K.length; i++) {
    X[i] = K[i] ^ NUMKEY[i];
  }
  section("X (decoded message, should be the same as ABCDEFGHI): " + toHex(X));
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to post another question about this. I've come to a point where I'm getting the hash numbers from the sequence through a home-made algorithm. I'll ask in a moment once I get the code up. BTW I was trying to beat the one pad thing.

Comment: @thexiv ah, I think I see, you're trying to invent a hash, not a cipher. XORing all the values together is a hash but very far from anything cryptographic (and not great at avoiding collisions if that's your goal). The Stanford crypto class on coursera is very good.

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm not interested in the cryptographic portion. I just wanted to use XOR cause it seemed like a cool idea. I'm actually into this for compression. I can avoid the collisions, that's easy. I just need a list of numbers that are unique. I can do that with a simple double-checking calculus algorithm. I can also use iterations through the loop I get the chars from. That i++; can be just as equally unique enough. It's just not fun to play with. :)

Comment: XOR is very cool and lots of fun… another fun one that might be applicable is modular exponentiation. Good luck (and keep having fun :)!

Comment: does this answer the question you asked if not the question you realized you should ask? (Yes, I'm fishing for points)

Comment: Well, here's one, if you can give me a definitive answer, it's worth it for me. How do I solve a `&` encryption? And is it just the opposite for a `|` encryption?

Comment: Bitwise AND and OR both lose information. You won't be able to reverse some of the bits even if you know the key

Comment: Wow, what pithy garbage machines they are then. I think I cracked XOR. Why would my code be spilling out chinese characters though?